# hyperref and bibunit: Keep the destination of the cite-link in the same bibunit

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, natbib, subfiles

I have a rather big and complex document with several bibunits and recurring citations. By default, all citations target the first appearance of a reference in a bibliography, leading to awkward jumps in the flow of the document and in irritating potential readers.

Unfortunately, the solution proposed in [this question and its answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618465/hyperref-links-to-first-appearance-of-bibliography-entry-when-using-bibunits) does not work for me because the bibunits are essentially `section*`, so there is not standard LaTeX counter available to disambiguate them. The bibunits are `\phantomsection`s but I don't know how to make use of this fact. The bibunits are also in `subfiles` if this helps to set something up.

Also, the solution proposed [in this older question and its answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99082/hyperref-and-bibunits-link-does-not-work) is not enough for me, because `natbib`'s `\citep` is used a lot and is not covered by the macros there.

What else can I do?

Comment: well you don't need a standard counter, any counter which makes the destinations unique would do it. hyperref uses in phantomsection `\Hy@linkcounter`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it helped me finding the most cromulent counter to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is a complete rewrite of the answer*. I found a solution to the problem that works at least for my project. It is definitely not a general solution (it does not handle compatibility with revtex, harvard, or chicago) and was achieved by deep surgery in the guts of `hyperref.sty`. For disambiguation of the bibunits the value of the counter `\the\@bibunitauxcnt` is inserted in the destination of the reference.

```
%hyperbu.sty
\ProvidesPackage{hyperbu}[2021/10/28 1.0 (JKn)]
%
% Makes Hyperlinks of citations and bibliographies local to bibunits
%
\RequirePackage{natbib}
\RequirePackage{bibunits}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\def\hyper@natlinkstart#1{%
  \Hy@backout{#1}%
  \hyper@linkstart{cite}{cite.\the\@bibunitauxcnt.#1}%
  \def\hyper@nat@current{#1}%
}
\def\hyper@natlinkend{%
  \hyper@linkend
}
\def\hyper@natlinkbreak#1#2{%
  \hyper@linkend#1\hyper@linkstart{cite}{cite.\the\@bibunitauxcnt.#2}%
}
\def\hyper@natanchorstart#1{%
  \Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{cite.\the\@bibunitauxcnt.#1}}%
}\def\hyper@natanchorstart#1{%
  \Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{cite.\the\@bibunitauxcnt.#1}}%
}
\def\hyper@natanchorend{\hyper@anchorend}
\ltx@IfUndefined{NAT@parse}{%
  \providecommand*\@extra@binfo{}%
  \providecommand*\@extra@b@citeb{}%
  \def\bibcite#1#2{%
    \@newl@bel{b}{#1\@extra@binfo}{%
      \hyper@@link[cite]{}{cite.\the\@bibunitauxcnt.#1    \@extra@b@citeb}{#2}%
    }%
  }%
  \gdef\@extra@binfo{}%
  \let\Hy@bibcite\bibcite
  \begingroup
    \@ifundefined{bbl@cite@choice}{}{%
      \g@addto@macro\bbl@cite@choice{%
        \let\bibcite\Hy@bibcite
      }%
    }%
  \endgroup
  \providecommand*{\@BIBLABEL}{\@biblabel}%
  \def\@lbibitem[#1]#2{%
    \@skiphyperreftrue
    \H@item[%
      \ifx\Hy@raisedlink\@empty
        \hyper@anchorstart{cite.\the\@bibunitauxcnt.#2\@extra@b@citeb}%
          \@BIBLABEL{#1}%
        \hyper@anchorend
      \else
        \Hy@raisedlink{%
          \hyper@anchorstart{cite.\the\@bibunitauxcnt.#2\@extra@b@citeb}\hyper@anchorend
        }%
        \@BIBLABEL{#1}%
      \fi
      \hfill
    ]%
\@skiphyperreffalse
\if@filesw
  \begingroup
    \let\protect\noexpand
    \immediate\write\@auxout{%
      \string\bibcite{#2}{#1}%
    }%
  \endgroup
\fi
\ignorespaces
}%
\def\@bibitem#1{%
\@skiphyperreftrue\H@item\@skiphyperreffalse
\Hy@raisedlink{%
  \hyper@anchorstart{cite.\the\@bibunitauxcnt.#1\@extra@b@citeb}\relax\hyper@anchorend
    }%
    \if@filesw
      \begingroup
        \let\protect\noexpand
        \immediate\write\@auxout{%
          \string\bibcite{#1}{\the\value{\@listctr}}%
        }%
      \endgroup
    \fi
    \ignorespaces
  }%
}{}
\endinput
```