hyperref with bibunits and a separate global bibliography: Having citations outside of any bibunit link to the global bibliography
This question is most similar to hyperref and bibunit: Keep the destination of the cite-link in the same bibunit, except that I am looking to have a global bibliography comprised of references cited outside of any bibunit.  The linked question's answer works perfectly for multiple bib units; however, when I cite the same reference both inside and outside of a bibunit, the citation in the bibunit correctly links to that bibunit's bibliography but the citation outside the bibunit links to the previous bibunit that has the reference instead of the global bibliography.
I've figured out a fix that works only if all citations exist after the last bibunit, that is, to call \global\advance\@bibunitauxcnt 1 after the last bibunit and before any of the remaining citations.  Advancing the counter makes these outside-of-bibunit citations and their targets distinct from those in the previous bibunits.  This works correctly in the below MWE.
However, if I uncomment the last chapter of in the below MWE, the previous citations' links lose their targets.  Is there a way around this so that I can have citations outside of any bibunits interspersed with bibunits in any order in the document?
The use case for this is if I have an executive summary with its own bibliography, any one of multiple appendices with its own bibliography, and all other citations from multiple chapters and other appendices in this report go to the global bibliography.  Thank you.
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}
\usepackage[subsectionbib]{bibunits}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperbu} % This is available in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/620422/263901

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Executive Summary}
\begin{bibunit}[ieeetr]
Second article~\cite{article2}. % This citation points to this bibunit's bibliography
\putbib[refs]
\end{bibunit}

\chapter*{Chapter with Bibliography 1}
\begin{bibunit}[ieeetr]
Second article~\cite{article2}. % This citation points to this bibunit's bibliography
\putbib[refs]
\end{bibunit}

\makeatletter
\global\advance\@bibunitauxcnt 1
\makeatother

\chapter{Chapter Using Global Bibliography} % No bibunit, just global bibliography
First article~\cite{article1}. % This citation points to the global bibliography
Second article~\cite{article2}. % This citation points to the previous bibunit's bibliography without the hyperbu package and to the global bibliography with the package

%% Uncommenting this chapter causes both of the previous chapter's citations links to lose their targets
%\chapter*{Chapter with Bibliography 2}
%\begin{bibunit}[ieeetr]
%Second article~\cite{article2}. % This citation points to this bibunit's bibliography
%\putbib[refs]
%\end{bibunit}

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}

Note:  I am stuck with using BibTeX, constrained by my school's custom .bst file.
