# Combining cite, bibunits, and hyperref: Links do not work

Tags: hyperref, cite-package, bibunits

When using the `cite`, `bibuints`, and `hyperref` packages together, there are no links from citations to the references list.  How can I get the links to exist while keeping the default `cite` citation sorting and my customization on `citepunct`?  Here's my MWE (you'll need your own "refs.bib" file with `article1` and `article2` entries):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{bibunits}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand\citepunct{], [}
\renewcommand\citedash{]--[}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Executive Summary}
\begin{bibunit}[ieeetr]
Second article~\cite{article2}.
\putbib[refs]
\end{bibunit}

\chapter{A Chapter}
First article~\cite{article1}.
Second article~\cite{article2}.
Both articles~\cite{article2,article1}.

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

I found similar questions on TeX StackExchange ([[1]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99082/263901), [[2]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/618465/263901), [[3]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/620413/263901)) that provide a solution to users using the `natbib` package, but these only partially work with `cite`.  Specifically, when I apply the code from both answers in [[1]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99082/263901), the links work but I lose the custom `citepunct` rendering and the automatic sorting that `cite` performs when citing multiple references in the same `\cite{}` command.  As such, `\cite{article2,article1}` renders as "[2, 1]" instead of the "[1], [2]" that my school requires.  How can I overcome this?  Thank you.

EDIT:  My school uses a custom .bst (BibTeX style) file so I [do not have the option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174979/263901) of switching to BibLaTeX and Biber.

Comment: why don't you use biblatex + biber? They support hyperref out of the box.

Comment: Good point, @UlrikeFischer.  Unfortunately, I'm stuck with needing to use my school's custom .bst file.  It is similar to the `ieeetr` style so I just used that in my MWE to keep it minimal.  I updated the question to incorporate this aspect.  Thank you.

Comment: I something stopping you from (a) changing `\usepackage{cite}` to `\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}` and (b) writing `\cite{article1}, \cite{article2}` to generate `[1], [2]`? BTW, your school's formatting requirements for citation call-outs are *insane*. I'm sure you're aware of this.

Comment: I tried @Mico's suggestion. For (a), I found no ability to redefine the `natbib` equivalent of `cite`'s `citedash`; it's hard-coded on line #416 of natbib.sty (v. 8.31b) so I would need to branch `natbib`. This affects having >2 citations appearing consecutively in the references list. For (b), I would need to sort all my multiple cites manually. Alternatively, I got the right `citepunct` with package options `numbers,square,sort&compress`, `\setcitestyle{citesep={], [}}`, and redefining `\NAT@spacechar{}`. It's doable once but not for improving the school's template, which I'd like to do.

Comment: Thank you to @Mico for this idea.  An hour later, I thought of `etoolbox`'s `\patchcmd`, tested it, and found that worked!  I probably would not have figured this out today without your help.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to an idea from @Mico in the comments of the initial question, that is, to replace `cite` with `natbib`, which necessitated some deep (but not wide) customization of `natbib` (v. 8.31b).  The trick was in overcoming `natbib`'s lack of hooks to modify attributes that `cite` calls `citepunct` and `citedash`.  In `natbib`, using `\setcitestyle` to modify `citesep` was not enough to have the same effect as `cite`'s `citepunct` because `natbib` always follows `citesep` with a space (`\` , to be exact).  Thus, I also had to redefine `\NAT@spacechar` from `{\ }` to `{}`.  The `citedash` was the only hard-coded aspect so I used `etoolbox`'s `\patchcmd` to replace the `--` with a `]--[`.

Here's the updated MWE with the solution:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[numbers,square,sort&compress]{natbib}
    \setcitestyle{citesep={], [}}
    \makeatletter
            \renewcommand\NAT@spacechar{}
            \patchcmd{\NAT@citexnum}{--}{]--[}{}{}
    \makeatother
\usepackage{bibunits}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Executive Summary}
\begin{bibunit}[ieeetr]
Second article~\cite{article2}.
\putbib[refs]
\end{bibunit}

\chapter{A Chapter}
First article~\cite{article1}.
Second article~\cite{article2}.
Both articles~\cite{article2,article1}.
All articles~\cite{article2,article1,article3}.

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

This is an answer to the question, "How can I keep the same citation style while overcoming the apparent conflict between the `cite`, `bibunits`, and `hyperref` packages that prevents the citation links to the references list from working?"